# How can I change the formula to detect the barcode in every angle? - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

How can I change the formula to detect the barcode in every angle?

[image: Formula]

[image: Original Image]
[image: Processed Image]

```
 rgb = imread('barcode4.jpg');
% Resize Image
rgb = imresize(rgb,0.33);
figure(),imshow(rgb);
% Convert from RGB to Gray
Igray = double(rgb2gray(rgb));
% Calculate the Gradients
[dIx, dIy] = gradient(Igray);
B = abs(dIx) - abs(dIy);
% Low-Pass Filtering
H = fspecial('gaussian', 20, 10);
C = imfilter(B, H);
C = imclearborder(C);
figure(),imagesc(C);colorbar
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the filter you have works well enough for you, you could simply use `imrotate` to create several rotated versions of the source image, and use the filter you have on each of them (make sure to use `bilinear` to get sensible derivatives)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. how can I create several rotated versions?? Sorry, I'm new to MatLab

Comment: I manage to get the barcode to vertical or horizontal. However the formula can only detect horizontal barcode. Can I change the formula so that both vertical and horizontal can detect the barcode.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31727-barcode-reader you can check out this link

Answer (score 7):

Your equation highlights areas where the magnitude of the gradient in the X direction is consistently higher than it is in the Y direction. To make this work in all directions, then you probably want areas where the magnitude of the gradient in any direction is high.

Try using the following:

```
B = double(sqrt(dIx.^2 + dIy.^2) > 0)
```

Not that this will basically highlight every edge, but the low-pass filter will mean that you need multiple edges close together.

Comment: Thanks for the coding! But I don't know where to put the code as I try replacing the formula, everything went green.

Comment: Try my updated version.

Comment: But now the whole image turn Red in color!!

Comment: I manage to get the barcode to vertical or horizontal. However the formula can only detect horizontal barcode. Can I change the formula so that both vertical and horizontal can detect the barcode.

Comment: I test this furmule '' B = double(sqrt(dIx.^2 + dIy.^2) > 0) " it's not work.